# How can I implement Swift enum associated values in C++?

Tags: c++, swift, enums

In Swift I'm implementing a state machine where the current state is represented by an enum value.  I associate extra data of varying types with each enum value.  Is there a way to do this in C++?  I can only think of using inheritance of some State class, but I would later have to use some kind of reflection and cast the State objects to get the extra associated data.

Comment: what about an enum and a map? And something like boost::variant for the data

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a base class representing the enum, and subclasses for each of the cases (each class having variables for the associated value for that case). The base class should be polymorphic (have at least one virtual method; probably a virtual destructor), so that the "enum" can be deconstructed by testing it against each case using `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::variant`.

```
namespace MyEnum {
    struct CaseA {};
    struct CaseB { int v; };
    struct CaseC { std::string s; float f; };
    using V = std::variant<CaseA, CaseB, CaseC>;
}

void foo(const MyEnum::V& myEnum) {
    ....
}

foo(MyEnum::CaseA{});
foo(MyEnum::CaseB{3});
foo(MyEnum::CaseC{.s = "abc", .f = 2.3f});
```

Comment: `variant` is nice for this since you can also do `switch` cases on the type like you can with a normal enum

Comment: @Human-Compiler how would you do a `switch` on the type of a `std::variant`? Do you mean switching on `index()`?

Comment: @intelfx no, that's not exhaustive and very cumbersome. Use this helper, it's somewhat better https://gist.github.com/tamaskenez/df15d148fd8b507167d9cfa644636561